# How to fetch the country name based on latitude and longitude in codename one..?

Tags: gps, codenameone, locationmanager

I am trying to retrieve the country name using Lat and Long I fetched using locationmanager in codename one... How to get country, state, city, zip based on these parameters..??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a webservice that will translate location data to location meta data e.g. this one https://www.codenameone.com/blog/dynamic-autocomplete.html

Notice that the sample above uses a different feature of that webservice but the same concept applies.

Comment: I tried above, but is it possible to pass like this..

Location loc = LocationManager.getLoationManager().getCurrentLocationSync(2000000);

r.addArgument("input", loc.toString());

as I want details based on Latitude and Longitude...

Comment: Check the google service that we query in the auto-complete demo, check its docs